# Rails scope for null or empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, rails-activerecord

I want to scope all the records where `cancelled_at` IS NULL or empty/blank.

I've found lots of posts asking for IS NOT NULL/empty/blank...but I need the opposite.

I'm sure it's painfully simple, but I'm stumped.

Here's what I've currently got:

```
scope :active, where("cancelled_at IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried that?

```
 Patient.where("created_at IS NULL or CAST(created_at as text) = ''")
 # SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE (created_at IS NULL or CAST(created_at as text) = '')
```

Comment: No go. Same effect as IS NULL: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."cancelled_at" IS NULL`

Comment: I need `is null` AND `empty`.

Comment: The same entry cannot be cancelled_at nil AND cancelled_at empty.

Comment: `cancelled_at` looks like a timestamp. You can't compare that to a string.

Comment: @MrYoshiji The field starts off as NULL, but then a user cancels and it sets the timestamp. Then, if they re-activate their account, it clears the timestamp (making it empty but not NULL).